Import single line from text file into json file
I have a really simple question which I am sure someone can answer really quickly for me.
I have one text file (password.txt) containing a random string of characters which has been generated by a Poweshell script to be used as a wifi password.
I have another script (change-password.ps1) which logs into my router and changes the password. I have managed to get this script to look at a json file (config.json) and use one of static passphrases.
This is my json file
{ "PSKs": {
            "01":"PSKforJanuary123!!",
            "02":"PSKforFebruary123!",
            "03":"PSKforMarch123!",
            "04":"PSKforApril123!",
            "05":"PSKforMay123!",
            "06":"PSKforJune123!",
            "07":"PSKforJuly123!",
            "08":"PSKforAugust123!",
            "09":"PSKforSeptember123!",
            "10":"PSKforOctober123!",
            "11":"PSKforNovember123!",
            "12":"PSKforDecember123!"
        }
    }

So instead of using one of these from the list above, how can I replace the "PSKfor***123!" with the line of text from my password.txt?
Or is there a way I can create this random string of characters within my json file without having to run another script to generate it?
Thanks in advance!

"how can I replace the "PSKfor***123!" with the line of text from my password.txt?" replace where? your question is not clear.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular it was indeed a typo, I have corrected it now

@SantiagoSquarzon Where it says "PSKformonth123" in my json file, I am trying to replace it with a random string to use as a password.

Which one of the PSKformonth123 ? The one that corresponds with the current month (i.e.: 12 in this case) ? These clarifications should be in your question

@SantiagoSquarzon Sorry, all of them. I want to replace all of them with the same single password or just one line which doesn't specify a month.
Once i have this worming I am going to run the script once a month so it generates a new one without having to check what month it is. It will change it every month regardless.

How to update all properties in the Json using a password stored in a file:
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.txt -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$pass = Get-Content path\to\password.txt
$json.PSKs.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object { $_.Value = $pass }
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content path\to\json.txt

How to update a single property in the Json using a password stored in a file, say for example, to dynamically update the property that corresponds with the current month:
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.txt -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$pass = Get-Content path\to\password.txt
$month = [datetime]::Now.ToString('MM')
# `$json.PSKs.$month` would work too here
$json.PSKs.PSObject.Properties[$month].Value = $pass
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content path\to\json.txt

How to update all properties using a randomly generated password, for this you will need to figure out what logic you want to use to generate a random password. A very easy way is via RandomNumberGenerator.GetString(ReadOnlySpan<Char>, Int32) Method but this method only works in PowerShell 7.
# `$chars` can be whatever you like, this is just an example
$chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%&_-+='.ToCharArray()
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.txt -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.PSKs.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    # `20` is for the string length
    $_.Value = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::GetString($chars, 20)
}
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content path\to\json.txt


Thats awesome! Thank you so much, this fixed my problem!
I finally went with this:
''$json = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\config.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$pass = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\luxion-guests.txt
$month = [datetime]::Now.ToString('MM')
$json.PSKs.$month would work too here
$json.PSKs.PSObject.Properties[$month].Value = $pass
$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\config.json''

Sorry I cannot get the hang of formatting on here :(

np glad it helped @Beckyboo

NOTE: my solutions require Powershell 7.x
Given you know the key, replacing all the values it's easy
$JsonHashTable = Get-Content -Path $JsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable -Depth 100
$PasswordString = Get-Content -Path $PasswordFile

# .Clone() necessary because otherwise the Keys list gets refreshed
# at every change and that causes a error.   
foreach ($Key in $JsonHashTable.PSKs.Keys.Clone()) {      
    $JsonHashTable.PSKs.$Key = $PasswordString 
}

$JsonHashTable | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $JsonFile

To change one specific month:
while ($MonthToChange -notin 1..12) {
    # Evaluate some error handling   
    [int]$MonthToChange = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert number of the month to change [0-12]'
}

$MonthKey = '{0:d2}' -f $MonthToChange

$JsonHashTable.PSKs.$MonthKey=$PasswordString

To dynamically generate a random string to use as password, given the apparent low-risk environment(you will have those passwords store in plain text after all) I'd suggest using
$PasswordString = New-Guid | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Guid

Depending on the real use situation, evaluate implementing some random string generator module.

Thanks for the response @sirtao, I have gone with the response above for now but I may come back to this at a later date.
